# How do I use LESS variables in CSS comments?

Tags: html, css, less

Is it possible to use LESS variables in CSS comments for mixins? I need that for spriting.

For example (not working / only the image path gets replaced):

```
.sprite (@width) {
    /** sprite: sprite-@{width}; sprite-image: url('../img/@{width}/sprite-@{width}.png'); sprite-layout: vertical */

    .picture {
        background-image: url('../img/@{width}/picture.png'); /** sprite-ref: sprite-@{width}; */
    }
}

.sprite(800);
```

Bonus question: Can I prevent the linebreak between background-image and the sprite-comment after compiling with lessc?

Comment: Why do this? The comments in the code are to help the developer, so no need to render them dynamically. Even, it is advisable remove unnecessary code (comments, line breaks, etc.) to reduce file size.

Comment: The comments are sprite directives for the sprite parser. They are needed to create sprites from the stylesheet dynamically. [SmartSprites](http://csssprites.org)

Comment: LESS support is planned for the next version. See the [uservoice](http://kentico.uservoice.com/forums/181512-features-development-models/suggestions/3472601-integrate-less-pre-processor-into-css-editor) idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you can't do variables in comments.

what about adding a property 'comment' ignored by browsers.

you could try to use an escaped string e.g.

```
prop: ~"url('blah'); /* comment */";
```

but it produces 2 semicolons (valid CSS) and is pretty hacky.

Comment: background-image: ~"url('../img/@{width}/picture.png'); /** sprite-ref: sprite-@{width}; */";
kind of works. But now I have problems with the relative path. The image does not load while using the clientside less.js parser.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this question because I wanted to have automated semantic comments that are fed into Kentico (a .NET CMS). Because the accepted answer seemed a bit unsatisfying I tried a few things on my own and managed to somehow produce a better solution. Maybe this is due to changes in the less syntax since then...

```
// DEFINITIONS
@A:   (~"A Standard");
@X-1: (~"1 General");

// BASIC DEFINITIONS
@start: (~"/*# ");
@end:   (~" #*/");
@sep:    (~" / ");

// FORMULA
@{start} @{A} @{sep} @{X-1} @{end}
* { text-decoration: none; }
```

The output is then:

```
/*# A Standard / 1 General #*/ * {
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

The only thing that's bothering me is the missing new line after the comment. Unfortunately I'm using the dotless Compiler which is not able to evaluate js-functions. I added an empty comment at the end, that did the trick for me.

Should you use the browser-version, you can use the following variable to insert a new line:

```
@nl: (~`"\n"`)
```

...resulting in:

```
@{start} @{A} @{sep} @{X-1} @{end} @{nl}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I have a good solution:

create a file and name it `start-comment.css`, inside the file add exactly this content `/*`, then create another file `end-comment.css`, inside add only this `*/`, and finally create another file e.g- `description.txt` in there, add all the content that you want in the comment, now in your `.less` file add the next code:

```
@import (inline) "start-comment.css";
@import (inline) "description.txt";
@import (inline) "end-comment.css";
```

at the end you will get something like this:

```
/*
(The content that i add in my text file)
*/
```